# Get user CITY location

Tags: php

Please, how to get user City with PHP? I wanna something like that eg:

If user is from New York, lets show text "hello you are in new york". If user is from Los Angeles, show "hello you are in LA". Of course i wanna use for other stuffs but the sintax is that.

O search in google and stack and don't find good solutions to that. Find by IP is not a good idea because here in brazil for exemple, our internet provider is on state capital, not on our region.. so found by ip register the internet provider location and not my location correctely.

Thanks if you know some solution about that.

Comment: Your google search term is [*geolocation*](http://google.com/search?q=geolocation+php) - the rest is up to you.

Comment: The key is know what to look for

Comment: There is not way to do this with 100% accuracy. IE, I can be using a proxy and appear to be from Singapore, while I am actually somewhere else. Same thing goes if someone connects over TOR.

Comment: You can use browser location features, if the user gives their permission. Mobile sites can sometimes use network approximate location features, using cell-tower info. Otherwise, you'll need services like Max Mind to get very approximate location data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do this in PHP, @ceejayoz makes a valid point that this will slow down your site dramatically if you're doing this on every page load.

A more scalable alternative is to do this on the client side, using javascript (or further, in this example, jQuery).

```
var url = "http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=24.66.128.2";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        alert(data.city);
        $('#city').text(data.city);
    });
});
```

See it in action, with your IP: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/wBzRr/

**Caveat: A)** this won't work for everyone, sometimes it returns "UNKNOWN CITY" -- you'll need to handle this gracefully, and **B)** it returns the state as well; you may want to write a simple regular expression to retrieve just the city part. Alternatively, you could use a more complex API provider to do this.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most reliable provider provides that service for free, e.g.

```
  http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=12.215.42.19
```

Result would be

> Country: UNITED STATES (US)
>   City: Sugar Grove, IL
>   IP: 12.215.42.19

From PHP

```
  $ip = '12.215.42.19';
  $info = file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=$ip");
```

Then with some text processing you can get the city easily.

**Enother way is** Use this api:

[ipinfodb](http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)

Comment: These will be wildly inaccurate at times. Mine says "unknown city", for example. Some GeoIP libs place me thousands of miles from my true location.

Comment: Yep, so you need to handle unknown city. Still the best way to do it with known geo locations.

Comment: You can also use `get_json.php` to return a JSON object.

Comment: @r3mus Not really. A `file_get_contents` call to an external API on every pageview is going to be **slow**.

Comment: @ceejayoz, for sure; the smart thing to do would be to make an asychronous API call through javascript on the client side.